# separate columns vs date datatype

Tags: php, sql

which is good practice and which will be more beneficial in future...keeping separate columns for date month and year in database or using a single date datatype column?

Comment: using single date datatype column

Comment: helps in date comparison , ordering by date column .. generating date value everytime by combining from seperate datepart columns is needless

Comment: Keeping separate columns : wastage of database. You have to create a new column like stamp for this datatype should be datetime

Comment: its much more useful to use a single datetime column (and format it according to your needs). this can the used to instantiate a proper datetime object which will allow all sorts of magic.

Answer (score 0):

Use a date datatype. Since sql supports date fields natively, its easy to filter for specific dates by using the WHERE clause.